# Why on Facebook can I not see someone online but only last active?

Tags: facebook-messenger

I open the Facebook app on my phone and go to chat and it tells me one person was last active ten minutes ago and then all of a sudden it says last active one minute ago but I never see a green dot to say they were online. Why is this?  It shows green dots for others but not this one person. It was happening throughout the night but then stopped at a certain time.

---

I only ask this because I have an anxiety along with other things and it plays on me at times. I just wondered is it a flaw with Facebook or something I should be concerned about. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a flaw.

This can work if the user is offline on Facebook Messenger and responded to a message recently (or even just opened that app)

Comment: so by turning off chat on your phone it wont say you are online but it will say when you were last active at that time of appearing offline?

Comment: @charles yes That is correct

Comment: I have recently noticed something else. A friend added a person as a friend and it shows under their profile of recently added but as of today that disappeared and it only happened two days ago. The stranger thing is that he is on her friends list but she is not in his.. Why is this?

Comment: @Charles I'm not sure what this has to do with the current question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can no longer see they became friends because now he/she can only see their friends or ungrounded that person

Answer (score -2):

If they have chat off (but they are online), it will keep reporting 1 minute ago until they log off.

Comment: Any source for this information?